# Is there a MouseDown setter property for a rectangle that acts as a button control template?

Tags: wpf, xaml

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a trigger property that triggers when the left mouse button is clicked over the button. Problem being my button has a rectangle as it's control template and I'd like to change the fill/stroke when the button/rectangle is clicked.

The only trigger property I can find that works is "IsMouseOver"

Anything like MouseDown or IsPressed doesn't work.

My xaml right now:

```
    <Button x:Name="my_Button" Click="my_Button_Click" Margin="268,91,-266,-94">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Margin="105,10,0,0" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Where the Trigger Property "IsMouseOver" is I would like the property to be MouseDown, and then proceeding to set the fill and stroke of the rectangle to different colors.

xaml I've tried that hasn't worked:

```
                                <Trigger Property="MouseDown" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                </Trigger>
```

Edit: I would like to clarify that IsMouseOver works perfectly with the trigger property, but I need it to be when the mouse is clicked on the button rather than hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `DataTrigger` below :

```
    <Button x:Name="my_Button" Click="my_Button_Click" Margin="268,91,-266,-94">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Margin="105,10,0,0" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```